# Skeptics favicon is almost invisible in the network profile activity list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, network-profile, favicon

Title says it all this time... in the network profile of users, the icon for [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) is almost invisible being only bright yellow on white. It appears both in activity list and top questions/answers.

Activity list: ([example](https://stackexchange.com/users/222226/ilya-melamed?tab=activity) of user active on skeptics)

> [image]

Top posts:

> [image]

Think it should have black background, same as in the accounts tab:

> [image]

Comment: Good thing you have a [FHRC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) to point it out. I otherwise wouldn't have seen it!

Comment: Maybe they don't believe in themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been silently fixed at some point, hooray!

> [image]